# How does React.cloneElement work with chldren?

Tags: reactjs

Surprisingly enough I didn't find any complete example of `React.cloneElement`.

Here is what the documentation says

```
React.cloneElement(
  element,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

All examples omit the `children` parameter but I don't understand why it has `...` in it. Is it a regular or splatted array? Can anyone provide a full example of how to clone an element with children?

It is also not clear to me whether existing children are preserved or removed from the clone? Since `props` are preserved and children are stored in props does it mean that children which we pass to `cloneElement` will be added to the existing children? If yes - in which order?

**UPDATE**

The problem is that we can describe children outside and inside of components and it's not clear how it works together.

Here is some code

```
const WithChildren = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>title inside WithChildren</h1>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

const Child = props => {
  return (
    <span>{props.val} child</span>
  )
}

const clone = React.cloneElement(
  <WithChildren a={0} c={42}>
    <p>some paragraph</p>
  </WithChildren>,
  {a: 1, b: 2},
  <Child val="first" />,
  <Child val="second" />
);
```

What will be the html of `clone` and why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this notation has nothing to do with arrays. The square brackets indicate optional parameters. The ellipsis indicates a variable number of parameters.

- `[props]` is an *optional* object that is shallowly merged with the original element's props to form the cloned element's props.
- `[...children]` is an *optional list* of children that, if specified, become the child in the cloned element, replacing `element`'s children if necessary.

It's quite typical for React components to accept multiple children, so it makes sense that `React.cloneElement` also accepts multiple children.

For example,

```jsx
React.cloneElement(
    <SomeComponent a={0} />,
    {a: 1, b: 2},
    <Foo />,
    <Bar />
);
```

is equivalent to

```jsx
<SomeComponent a={1} b={2}>
    <Foo />
    <Bar />
</SomeComponent>
```

Conceptually, `React.cloneElement` is something like this:

```jsx
function cloneElement(element, props, ...children) {
    return (
        <element.type
            {...element.props}
            {...props}
            ref={child.ref}
            key={child.key}
        >
            {children}
        </element.type>
    );
}
```

**UPDATE**

In response to the update in the question:

The clone will be

```
<WithChildren a={1} b={2} c={42}>
  <Child val="first" />
  <Child val="second" />
</WithChildren>
```

As for the *why*, it's explained in the docs:

> The resulting element will have the original element’s props with the new props merged in shallowly.

This means the cloned element's props are calculated as

```js
Object.assign(
    {a: 0, c: 42}, // original props
    {a: 1, b: 2}   // new props
)
```

which is `{a: 0, b: 2, c: 42}`.

> New children will replace existing children.

This means

```jsx
<Child val="first" />
<Child val="second" />
```

completely replaces

```jsx
<p>some paragraph</p>
```

If you want to go deeper into the *why*, best to ask the React devs :)